# breeze.js : how do I exclude tables/entities from breeze metadata collection?

Tags: javascript, metadata, breeze

I have a Single-Page application using Entity Framework on the backend and Breeze.js on the client. I'm also using the breeze .Net EF classes. In order for the breeze client to create breeze entities on the client, it calls a controller method named "MetaData". This method returns a collection of all the entities in the database, even those that may not be used on the client.

Even though there is no coding logic in the metadata, it does contain a complete schema of the database. Some of these entities are used for security and business logic, and I wish to not have this entire structure open to the world.

Is there a way to exclude entities (not just individual properties) from the breezejs metadata collection?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easy way is to create a `DbContext` that has only those classes and relationships that you want to expose. Use the fluent interface to shrink it down and cauterize relationships that you don't want.

Then create an instance of an `EfContextProvider` based on this limited `DbContext`.

You can use this cut-down `DbContext` exclusively for metadata generation if you wish. You can switch to something more robust (wrapped in a different `EfContextProvider`) if you must.

See the documentation chapter ["EF as a Design Tool"](http://breeze.github.io/doc-js/metadata-with-ef.html).

Comment: I think that will work but I seem to have a misunderstanding on how Breeze determines which entities to include/exclude.  Ignore this separate  DBContext class for a moment.  In a single DBContext/EfContextProvider scenario breeze is loading all entities (about 20) in the metadata, even though I have only 3 DbSet's in my context class.  Is breeze reading the edmx file for entities and relationships?  Would you have an example of a fluent statement to exclude an entity?  Thanks

Comment: figured it out, I think.  The entire list of entities were included due to relationships.  The 3 DbSet's entities had FK relationships to other entities, and those had relationships, etc.  So the entire db was brought into metadata.  I found the modelBuilder.Ignore statement.  It looks like that will work for me.